# Problem with angular-cli "ng build --prod"

Tags: angular6

I use `ng build --prod` to build my project, when visit one page of this project, there occured an error which is:

```
main.afefcc77e57d8548ac9f.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(r)[t -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
Error: StaticInjectorError(r)[t -> t]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[t -> t]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

But if I use `ng build` to build my project, the error does not occur?

Comment: There is a discussion : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11179
It likes a bug with angular-cli